# How to handle % in query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have query `Select * from table1 where name like '%Whateveruserpassintextbox%'`.

When user passing `%` in textbox query returns all the table data.

What is the proper way to handle this type of scenario ?

Comment: The proper way is to explain what you want. Only after you know that, you can implement it...

Comment: Any thoughts on SQL injection?

Comment: When user enter % he should only get data which matches with % in named.

Comment: Smells like [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing `\%`  Matches one “%” character. Read more on [MySql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

> To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by the escape character. If you do not specify the **ESCAPE** character, “\” is assumed.

```
 -----------------------------------------
|   String   |  Description               |
 -----------------------------------------
|    \%      |  Matches one “%” character |
|    \_      |  Matches one “_” character |
 -----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

For a start, a query like that is known as a performance killer. It's usually questionable that you should be doing it at all.

But, if the user passes in `%`, you need to escape it with something like:

```
select * from table1
where name like '%50\% off sale%'
escape "\";
```

I think `\` is actually the default escape character but I tend to explicitly specify it in case the default might ever change.

So basically, you pre-process the string to replace `%` with `\%` *before* you place it between the two `%` markers at the ends.

You should also be passing any user input through a filter like [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html), to prevent SQL injection attacks. Do this before you do the pre-processing suggested above so that your `\%` inadvertently turns into `\\%`.

As well as the `'%'` "any number of characters" wildcard, you should also escape the `'_'` "exactly one character" wildcard, lest `user_name` will also match things like `usersname`.

So the process would be:

- get string from user.
- pass that through `mysql_real_escape_string`.
- further clean it up by replacing all `%` with `\%`.
- further clean it up by replacing all `_` with `\_`.

Only then should you even *begin* to think about the merest possibility that you might want to consider using that string :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$search=$_POST['whatuserTypes'];

if($search == '%')
{
$query=("Select * from table1;");
}
else
{
   $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name like '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($search));
}
```